# How to connect two registered users in Django

Tags: python, django, database, algorithm, django-forms

I have a Django 2.1.5 app in which I have created two different forms, onto which registered users can post their requirements, for example : *"I need a vehicle to go from point A to B"*, or *"I need to go from D to E tomorrow"*. And, other users can post their services as in *"I have a truck free that can go from A to B"* etc. So, I have 2 boards, one is for people who need vehicles, and other where people are posting they have free vehicles. Now, I have two different pages for both boards, and two different forms for each board. Now, if I find a requirement which I can fulfil, then there is a button which says 'Bid your price'. After which, I provide my details and a bidding price for the person asking. Then, this information is to be sent to the original author of that requirement. *I need to figure out how to connect these two registered people. Should I just give every requirement and service offer a unique URL? and same for every user ? Or is there any other method ? I am really stumped here on what is the best way to do this.*

Comment: Please share your code with us. Avoid writing huge text blobs while asking a question on SO.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @abhi do you mean I should post my views,models and forms.py ?? I really need a direction or logic or a method that could be implemented in django, rather than code answer. Which is why I did not add it, but I will if it will help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you should have a model `Requirement` with fields, but more specifically `type = [PASSENGER, DRIVER]`. You show those `Requirement`s on different listings for different types of users and once they find what they're looking for they click on a button `Bid your price` which links them to a view `/bids/new` where they fill the form or whatever and as the end product there's an instance of `Bid` (fields you need + fk  `Requirement` bid was created for).

Comment: Thanks! That definitely makes sense, wonder why I could not find such a solution online. Is there any example or tutorial where something like this was used ?

Comment: you couldn't find anything probably because it sounds like a task and not like a question. I would start with reading tutorials on ModelForm https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms#ModelForms